# switch statement inside of an if statement

Tags: php

can I do something like this I think I might have it set up wrong.

I am loading 2 different page formats, $current_subject or $current_page. I think the switch is what I want for loading the $current_subject. but how do I add the $current_page into the switch, or would I do it like what I set up?

it doesn't seem right like I might be doing it wrong so I thought I would ask.

I guess what I am saying is. is this the right way to do it, or is there a more semantic way of doing it?

```
if ($current_subject) {
    switch ($current_subject["id"]) {
    case 8:
    echo page_content() . "<br />" . list_archives();
    break;
    case 4:
    case 5:
    echo all_post_content();
    break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 3:
    echo page_content();
    break;
    case 7:
    echo contact();
    break;
    }
} elseif ($current_page) {
    echo "<h1>". htmlentities ($current_page ["menu_name"])."</h1>";
    echo "<p class=\"name\"><em>Posted by: " . htmlentities ($current_page ["author"]) . post_date () . "</em></p>";
    echo "<p>". nl2br(htmlentities($current_page ["content"])) . "</p><br />";
}
```

Comment: you can nest switches/ifs as deep as you want. But consider how **UGLY** that gets, especially if this code has to ever get maintained by other people.

Comment: i know it looks "ugly" i guess i am trying to find out what would be the right way of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There's no syntactic barrier here, and no particular best practice broken.